# Find and replace in yml file

Tags: bash, yq

I have following yml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: queue
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: queue
  replicas: 1
  template: # template for the pods
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: queue
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: 
        image: 
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 300Mi
```

I need to specify name and image in Deployments section
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: queue

I need to enter following string in this file for  Deployment 
under

```
 spec:
      containers:
```

section.

```
go:dev
go:latest
```

**Desired output**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: queue
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: queue
      replicas: 1
      template: # template for the pods
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: queue
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: go:dev
            image: go:latest
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: 300Mi
```

Is it possible to perform above with shell script using some regex or similar ?

Comment: IMHO, experts advice not to parse ymals with `awk`, `sed` etc so adding `yq` a proper parser for ymal in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RavinderSingh13 is right about not using `awk`, `sed` or some other string utilities for this. Using `yq` is the correct way to do this.

https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/

I used `yq version 4.6.3`.

To update each property individually, run the following commands. The `-i` modify the file inplace.

```
yq -i eval '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].name = "go:dev"' file.yml
yq -i eval '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = "go:latest"' file.yml
```

`yq` query result can also be piped into each other. This can be leverage here to update both field in a single command.

```
yq -i eval '.spec.template.spec.containers[0].name = "go:dev" | 
            .spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = "go:latest"' file.yml
```